# SQL: Recursive Path

Tags: sql, tree

Is it possible to create a "tree resolver" in SQL?

I have a table:

```
ID Name Parent
1  a
2  b    1
3  c    1
4  d    3
```

Now I want a SQL query that returns:

```
ID   PATH
1    /a
2    /a/b
3    /a/c
4    /a/c/d
```

Is this possible with SQL? It would make many things easier for me. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: It's probably possible but the syntax will vary from one brand of SQL to another, and it might *not* be possible in all brands. What are you using? MySQL? Oracle? MS SQL? A good place to start would be to look up "recursive SQL" or "recursive SQL queries" on google, but be aware the solutions may be specific to particular brands of SQL.

Comment: I'm using DB2. It's interresting that there is no general solution.

Comment: the general solution is to store the path in your database. Google `materialized path`.

Comment: The problem is: I'm working on an existing project that used to create those paths using program logic after a SELECT *. I just thought: "That's horrible. This should be handled by the database." Unfortunately I can't make any changes to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what database server use, this functionality may be provided for you already. Otherwise you can create a function that call itself to return this information, or implement a [Materialized Path](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&ei=g5jZS8O5I8L88Aap9IBU&sa=X&oi=spellfullpage&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=2&ved=0CBQQvwUoAQ&q=materialized+path&spell=1) solution.

**Update:**

For DB2 you can make use of [Recursive Common Table Expressions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.apsg/db2z_xmprecursivecte.htm).

Answer (score 7):

Using CTE in sql server 2005 and later, here's a snippet that I have to do this:

```
WITH Paths([Level], [FullPath], [ID]) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        0 AS [Level], 
        Name AS FullPath, 
        ID
    FROM dbo.Entity
    WHERE (ParentEntityID IS NULL)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        p.[Level] + 1 AS [Level], 
        CASE RIGHT(p.[FullPath], 1) 
        WHEN '\' THEN p.[FullPath] + c.[Name] 
        ELSE p.[FullPath] + '\' + c.[Name] 
    END AS FullPath, 
    c.ID
    FROM dbo.Entity AS c 
    INNER JOIN Paths AS p ON p.ID = c.ParentEntityID
)
SELECT [FullPath], [ID]
FROM Paths
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, look [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html). You can use the "start with" and "connect by prior" statements, I've used this in the past to create breadcrumbs in a web app.

Comment: That's Oracle-specific. Is there a generic solution?

Comment: The question is "is it possible". My answer is "yes, it is". Can't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to represent a tree in an SQL database.  I guess I don't know much, but I do know that Django Treebeard uses 3 different ways to do it.  If you look at the documentation, it has short descriptions of each way:

[adjacency list](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/1.60/al_tree.html) -- what you're doing already

[materialized path](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/1.60/mp_tree.html) -- article: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_patterns_trees.htm

[nested sets](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/1.60/ns_tree.html) -- oh, here's wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a simple table called DLFolder with the following columns:

```
| folderId | name | parentFolderId |
```

In Oracle you can use the `sys_connect_by_path` operation.

```
select fo.folderId as folder_id, sys_connect_by_path(fo.name, '/') as relname
from DLFolder fo
start with fo.parentFolderId=0
connect by prior fo.folderId = fo.parentFolderId
```

Will give the following result:

```
/1020_Training_Material
/1020_Training_Material/2000_IBBA
/1020_Training_Material/2000_IBBA/5000_FR
/1020_Training_Material/2000_IBBA/5050_NL
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions164.htm