# Get Left side from binary tree from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, binary-tree

My Table structure is,

```
username        leg1        leg2
------------------------------------
user1           user2       user7
user2           user3       user8
user3           user4       user9
user4           user5       test
user5           user6       user10
```

[image]

I  need to get left tree of user1 (need to get tree based on leg1)

```
Username
--------

user2
user3
user4
user5
```

My updated question

Its working in minimum record. but if i used this SP in max no.of record(I have 4200 Records). It shows the error as "#1456 - Recursive limit 255 (as set by the max_sp_recursion_depth variable) was exceeded for routine getFinal "

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `getFinal`(IN `param_name` VARCHAR(255), OUT `result` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  DECLARE `next_param_name` VARCHAR(255);
   SELECT `leg1` INTO `next_param_name`  FROM `matrix`  WHERE `username` = `param_name`;
    IF `next_param_name` IS NULL THEN
    SET `result` := `param_name`;
  ELSE     
    CALL `getFinal`(`next_param_name`, `result`);
 END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support recursive calls, So you can not do that with traditional SQL queries.
You can build a function in your desired programming language that you use, Or I think you can use Stored procedure.

Comment: I have tried using stored procedure. but mysql shows error like #1414 - OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine sample.getVolume is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger
--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getVolume( IN param_name VARCHAR(255), OUT result VARCHAR(255 ))
BEGIN 
SELECT leg1 INTO result FROM employee WHERE emp_name = param_name ;
IF result IS NULL THEN
select result;
ELSE     
CALL getVolume(result, '');
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

-
SET @@GLOBAL.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
SET @@session.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255; 
call getVolume('user1', @result);
select @result;

Comment: I am sorry for late,
I wrote you some code I think you will benefit from it:
`BEGIN

Declare r varchar(25);
SELECT leg1 INTO r FROM employee WHERE username = param_name;

IF r IS NOT NULL THEN
 select r;
 CALL getVolume(r, result);
 END IF;
 
END`
change table and column names to yours, test it then tell me the result.

Comment: Thanks Wajeeh. Its working in minimum record. but if i used this SP in max no.of record(I have 4200 Records). It shows the error as "#1456 - Recursive limit 255 (as set by the max_sp_recursion_depth variable) was exceeded for routine getFinal ". Please see my updated question and guide to fix it.

Comment: Welcome, As I told you "MySQL" does not support full recursive call, So I prefer doing what you want on the programming language that use this database, Or you can change your design to something else. I wrote a previous opinion about problems like those you can check it
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33698807/5559741