# SQL: Get all relationships recursively with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume we have the following two tables:

**Main Table**

```
id | number
1  | 5
2  | 3
3  | 4
4  | 5
```

**pivot Table**

```
primary | secondary
1       | 2
2       | 3
3       | 4
```

In the pivot table I define many to many relationships between the elements of the main table.

Let's set a destination number to 10.
Now I want to get all the relationship-combinations recursively but only when the sum of the column "number" of all related elements is smaller then the desired number "10".

So first we get all elements without any related elements:

```
1: 5
2: 3
3: 4
4: 5
```

Because there's no element that has "10" or more I would like to get the first level relationships. So:

```
1-2: 8 // Sum of both elements
2-3: 7
3-4: 9
```

As you can see I also don't want the combination 2-1 because we allready have 1-2.
There's no combination with "10" or more so get the next level:

```
1-2-3: 12 // result because 12 is greater than 10
2-3-4: 12 // also a possible result
```

As the result I want all element-ids that are necessary.
Thanks for any help.

PS: I'm new to writing questions on stackoverflow so please forgive my bad text-format.

Comment: Your sample data is too short to properly understand the problem. Add some more dataset.

Comment: I've added a new element so now we get 2 possible results in the end

Comment: what about `1-2-3-4` ?

Comment: OK, and now the only possible combination left is `1-2-3-4: 17`(in case if your number is 15). Did I get it right?

Comment: @Shaharyar yeah you're right :)

Comment: @wajeeh this combination is not necessary if the desired number is 10. I just want the "smallest" possible combination

Comment: unfortunately `MySQL` doesn't support recursive. it needs a lot of effort to solve it using `MySQL`, if you don't have big number of data I advice you to make it with a higher code like `PHP` or what ever you use.

Comment: @wajeeh yeah I was thinking about this. So I'll have to make multiple SQL-Queries for each level, right?

Comment: Yes, I think that. I think you can benefit from this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/33698807/5559741 if you can change your DB design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you restrict entries to `pivot` so that `primary < secondary` you can avoid duplicates. Here's a first pass which does the first 4 levels. Since the pattern is predictable, it should be possible to have a loop which builds the query-string for each increasing level in the loop and then executes it dynamically. It would exit when the first query returned rows.

```
-- Level 1
select * from t1_main t where number > 10

-- Level 2
select p.pri, p.sec, m1.number + m2.number
from t1_pivot p 
inner join t1_main m1 on m1.id = p.pri 
inner join t1_main m2 on m2.id = p.sec
where m1.number + m2.number > 10

-- Level 3
select p1.pri, p1.sec, p2.sec, m1.number + m2.number + m3.number 
from t1_pivot p1 
inner join t1_pivot p2 on p1.sec = p2.pri
inner join t1_main m1 on m1.id = p1.pri 
inner join t1_main m2 on m2.id = p1.sec
inner join t1_main m3 on m3.id = p2.sec
where m1.number + m2.number + m3.number > 10

-- Level 4
select p1.pri, p1.sec, p2.sec, p3.sec, m1.number + m2.number + m3.number + m4.number
from t1_pivot p1 
inner join t1_pivot p2 on p1.sec = p2.pri 
inner join t1_pivot p3 on p2.sec = p3.pri
inner join t1_main m1 on m1.id = p1.pri 
inner join t1_main m2 on m2.id = p1.sec
inner join t1_main m3 on m3.id = p2.sec
inner join t1_main m4 on m4.id = p3.sec
where m1.number + m2.number + m3.number + m4.number > 10
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you :)

Comment: I decided to choose this solution. Works well. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved answer for Sql Server 2008 R2, which hopefully you can adapt to MySQL. It will recurse to any depth. You end with a table with columns `tuple` (eg '1' or '1-2' or '1-2-3'), `number` (sum of the number values of all the `id`s in the tuple) and the level in `lvl`. You can then select the rows with the lowest level.
I like short names to avoid fat-finger mistakes so have used `pri` for `primary` and `sec` for `secondary`.

```
create table #summary ( tuple varchar(max), sec int, number int, lvl int )

delete #summary
insert #summary( tuple, sec, number, lvl )
select cast(p.pri as varchar(max)) + '-' + cast(p.sec as varchar(max)) as tuple, 
    p.sec, m1.number + m2.number as number, 1 as lvl
from t1_pivot p 
inner join t1_main m1 on m1.id = p.pri 
inner join t1_main m2 on m2.id = p.sec

declare @rows int = 1, @lvl int = 1
while @rows > 0 begin
    insert #summary( tuple, sec, number, lvl )
    select s.tuple + '-' + cast(p.sec as varchar(max)) as tuple, 
        p.sec, s.number + m.number as number, s.lvl + 1 as lvl
    from #summary s 
    inner join t1_pivot p on p.pri = s.sec
    inner join t1_main m on m.id = p.sec
    where s.lvl = @lvl 
    set @rows = @@rowcount
    print @rows
    set @lvl = @lvl + 1
end

select * from (
    select * from #summary
    union select cast(id as varchar(max)) as tuple, 0 as sec, number, 0 as lvl from t1_main
) x
where x.number > 10
order by lvl, tuple
```

Here's the resultset. Ignore `sec` - it is only needed when building the resultset.

```
tuple       sec number  lvl
1-2-3       3   12      2
2-3-4       4   12      2
1-2-3-4     4   17      3
```

Originally I used Sql Server Common Table Expression (CTE), and then adapted it to run in a loop (as above) which is more generic. This code is attached for interest because I found it very easy to play with.

```
with summary as (
    select cast(p.pri as varchar(max)) + '-' + cast(p.sec as varchar(max)) as tuple, 
        p.sec, m1.number + m2.number as number, 1 as lvl
    from t1_pivot p 
    inner join t1_main m1 on m1.id = p.pri 
    inner join t1_main m2 on m2.id = p.sec

    union all

    select s.tuple + '-' + cast(p.sec as varchar(max)) as tuple, 
        p.sec, s.number + m.number as number, lvl + 1 as lvl
    from summary s 
    inner join t1_pivot p on p.pri = s.sec
    inner join t1_main m on m.id = p.sec
)
select * from (
    select * from summary
    union select cast(id as varchar(max)) as tuple, 0 as sec, number, 0 as lvl from t1_main
) x
where x.number > 10
order by lvl, tuple
```

Comment: I will try this as well. Thank you very much :)